# Could spooky action at a distance be explained by particles staying linked in another dimension?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, wormholes

The math suggests that there are 11 or more "dimensions", most of which we know very little about.  What if entangled particles are linked in one of those "other dimensions" and when we separate them in our view of space and time they remain linked in their other dimension.  That way, there is no need to transmit information across vast distances since they never separate in their dimension.

Comment: To those who are voting to close, this question is more or less layman's interpolation to “**ER=EPR**” conjecture, which is “mainstream” and has a clear meaning.

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v2): Replace the word _other dimensions_ with the word _wormholes._

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather speculative *conjecture* that indeed, [quantum entaglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) (which is a proper name for “spooky action at a distance”) could be explained via entangled objects being linked via a special kind of spacetime construct, [Einstein–Rosen bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Schwarzschild_wormholes), a variant of a non-traversable [wormhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole). This conjecture is referred to as **ER=EPR** by the initials of authors who wrote the first paper on wormholes (Albert Einstein and Nathan Rosen) and the first paper on entanglement (Einstein, Boris Podolsky and Rosen). Though the papers from 1935 share two of the authors, they are about different areas of physics and only in 2014 it was suggested that the concepts could be related.

For more details about the conjecture I refer to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER%3DEPR), and to a lecture by L. Susskind, *Copenhagen vs Everett, Teleportation, and ER=EPR* [arXiv:1604.02589](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02589). *(This text doesn't have complex equations, but it is 38 pages long, although probably the first ten would be enough to get what it is about)*.

A couple of images from the lecture:
[image: Fig 2 and 3 from L. Susskind's lecture. Equality symbol added by me]

Note, that when people are trying to visualize wormholes they are often drawing the *embedding diagrams* (such as this one):

[image: ER bridge embedding]

But such images do not mean that the wormhole that we are visualizing is a link existing in some additional external space of higher dimensionality, this is just a visual aid. Mathematically the wormhole geometry is specified using internal description without using the *embedding* space. So the ER=EPR conjecture is actually independent of the additional space-time dimensions, it does not need them to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's dimensions, and then there's dimensions.

In some theories there are indeed many more dimensions, and 11 pops out in most of those due to some underlying "observables". But it is important to note that, unlike the four dimensions you're familiar with, these subatomic dimensions are "[compactified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(physics))".

What that means, practically, is that they have very small physical "span". So in the end, the answer is "no, that doesn't help", because these dimensions do not connect different locations in macroscopic space, they're just too small.

BTW the idea that there is something to fix is largely abandoned. When I was in uni it was all about microscopic wormholes that did this connection, but the same basic concept.  But the real question remains, "what is spooky"? If you think this is too weird to contemplate then you try to solve the problem (mostly with even weirder things), but if you don't think it's a problem, then there's nothing to solve in the first place.